# how to ignore continuous space and tab in text in java.

Tags: java, regex

I have problem in getting rid of multiple white space and tabs from a text file while extracting into an array.

Here is what I have done:

```
arrayofpara = bufdocument.split("[\\r\\n]+\\s");
```

Let me know what could be wrong with above code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you want to do exactly?

Now you split on a series of "newline" characters followed by exactly one whitespace character. My guess you want to remove all the following (and preceeding?) whitespace characters. Then you need to add a quantifier to the whitespace character:

Try

```
 arrayofpara = bufdocument.split("\\s*[\\r\\n]+\\s*");
```

This will split also on newlines, that are not followed by whitespace characters, because `\\s*` will match 0 or more whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks! Its working. Wasted 3 days to get this, thanks a lot!!